# laravel search many to many Relashionship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am testing eloquent for the first time and I want to see if it suit my application.

I have Product table:

```
id, name
```

and model:

```
class Produit extends Eloquent {

    public function eavs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Eav')
                ->withPivot('value_int', 'value_varchar', 'value_date');
    }
}
```

and eav table:

```
id, name, code, field_type
```

and pivot table:

```
product_id, eav_id, value_int, value_varchar, value_date
```

class Eav extends Eloquent {

```
public function produitTypes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
            'ProduitType'
            ->withPivot('cs_attributs_produits_types_required');
}
```

All this is working. 
But I want to search in that relashionship:
e.g: all product that  have eav_id=3 and value_int=3

I have tested this:

```
$produits = Produit::with( array('eavs' => function($query)
    {
        $query->where('id', '3')->where('value_int', '3');
    }))->get();
```

But I get all the product, and eav data only for these who have id=3 and value_int=3.

I want to get only the product that match this search...
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion and something I like to follow is to *start with what you know*.  In this case, we know the `eav_id`, so let's go from there.

`$produits = Eav::find(3)->produits()->where('value_int', '3')->get();`

Eager loading in this case isn't going to save you any performance because we are cutting down the 1+n query problem as described in the documentation because we are starting off with using `find()`.  It's also going to be a lot easier to read and understand.

Using query builder for checking multiple eavs

```
$produits = DB::table('produits')
    ->join('eav_produit', 'eav_produit.produit_id', '=', 'produits.id')
    ->join('eavs', 'eavs.id', '=', 'eav_produit.eav_id')
    ->where(function($query)
    {
        $query->where('eav_produit.value_int','=','3');
        $query->where('eavs.id', '=', '3');
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query)
    {
        $query->where('eav_produit.value_int','=','1');
        $query->where('eavs.id', '=', '1');         
    })
    ->select('produits.*')
    ->get();
```

Making it work with what you already have...

```
$produits = Produit::with( array('eavs' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('id', '3')->where('value_int', '3');
    $query->orWhere('id', '1')->where('value_int', '1');
}))->get();

foreach($produits as $produit)
{
    if(!produit->eavs)
        continue;

    // Do stuff 
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will test that. But if i need to search all Produit which have at the same time an eav like this(eav->id = 3 AND value_int = 3) AND also another eav like this (eav->id = 1 AND value_int = 2)

Comment: Maybe it's best to go with the query builder if you need to keep adding on, or stick with what you have and put checks in while looping so as to not echo produits.

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is very old. But added the answer that works in the latest versions of Laravel.

In Laravel 6.x+ versions you can use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method.

So your query will look like this:

```
Produit::whereHas('eavs', function (Builder $query) {
    // Query the pivot table
    $query->where('eav_id', 3);
})->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent:

```
When accessing the records for a model, you may wish to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship. For example, you wish to pull all blog posts that have at least one comment. To do so, you may use the has method

$posts = Post::has('comments')->get();
```

Using the "has()" method should give you an array with only products that have EAV that match your criteria.

```
$produits = Produit::with( array('eavs' => function($query)
    {
        $query->where('id', '3')->where('value_int', '3');
    }))->has('eavs')->get();
```

Comment: ->has('eavs') will return only Produits with at least one eavs but I need Produits with at least one eavs that match my query